# Where is the bug in my polynomial calculation code?

Tags: c, macos, gcc

my aim is to compare the two different method to calculate a polynomial..
but if you run it on a mac (my computer is MacBook Air)
you will find the two results are different...
.but....
if you delete the "/* ... */" part OR delete the two "//" before "for ..."
it works fine...

plus..it works fine on linux...

can anyone tell me why?..

here is my program:

```
#define MAX_NUM 10
#define TEST_TIME 1
#define test_type double

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

test_type normal_method(test_type *a, test_type x, int degree)
{
    test_type s = 0.0;
    test_type e = 1.0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++) {
        s += a[i] * e;
        e *= x;
    }

    printf("%lf\n", s);

    return s;
}

test_type horner_method(test_type *a, test_type x, int degree)
{
    test_type s = a[degree];

    for (int i = degree - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        s *= x;
        s += a[i];
    }

    printf("%lf\n", s);

    return s;
}

void generate_data(test_type *a, test_type *x, int degree)
{
    srand( time(NULL) );
    for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++) {
        a[i] = (test_type)(rand() % MAX_NUM + 1) / (test_type)(rand() % MAX_NUM + 1);
        *x = (test_type)(rand() % MAX_NUM + 1) / (test_type)(rand() % MAX_NUM + 1);
    }

}

int main()
{
    const int degree = 10;
    test_type a[degree];
    test_type x;

    generate_data(a, &x, degree);

//Just by clear the /**/ below, the program will work fine....
/*    
    printf("x = %lf\n", x);
    for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++) {
        printf("%lf\n", a[i]);
    }
*/
    clock_t begin, end;

//  Or clear the two // below, it will work fine too....

    begin = clock();
//    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_TIME; i++) 
        normal_method(a, x, degree);
    end = clock();
    printf("The normal method used %d clock times\n", end - begin);

    begin = clock();
//    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_TIME; i++)
        horner_method(a, x, degree);
    end = clock();
    printf("The horner method used %d clock times\n", end - begin);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First it's not an amazing problem. Second what's with the giant comment block before the code saying theirs not enough code context.

Comment: Yes, this problem would better be entitled “program changes behavior when I remove comments”.

Comment: You also define an array of capacity 10, but later write to index 10 of it (which is the eleventh element).

Answer (score 5):

You are accessing memory that is out of bounds of the array you create in `main` and use in the other functions. This happens in at least three places.

- The loop bounds in `normal_method` go from zero to ten:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++) {  // a[degree] is out of bounds
  ```
- On the first line of `horner_method` you are accessing memory that is out of bounds of your array:

  ```
  test_type s = a[degree];  // a[degree] is out of bounds
  ```
- The loop bounds in `generate_data` are incorrect the same way as in `normal_method`:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++) {  // a[degree] is out of bounds
  ```

Comment: And also `generate_data` writes eleven elements ("`i <= degree`").

Comment: Good catch. I will update the answer to add that. The loop bounds in `normal_method` are similarly incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `%lf` to print a `double`. Just `%f` is fine. You probably confused that with `scanf`, which needs the `l`.

With the compiler warning options `-Wall -Wextra -Wformat=2` gcc should tell you what's wrong in your code.